# How can I highlight multiple occurrences of a single word in an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am working on a HTML/JS based web-chat application. And I would like to search through the chat window for all the occurrences of a particular word. The current idea for implementing this search is, I would filter through chat message history and scan each chat message. Each chat message is wrapped within a specified HTML element and if the chat message element contains the searched word, I will manipulate the DOM to highlight this particular searched word.

So as of now, I have a dummy implementation which goes through all the chat messages and searches for the word within each chat message. However, in cases where there are multiple occurrences of the word within a single chat message, the search function is only able to highlight the first occurrence. How can I highlight (manipulate DOM) for all such occurrences of words in a single chat message.

The following is the current code snippet that I have written:

```
 _scrollChatMessageAndHighlightResult = async(searchText) => {
        // perform DOM operations to find the text and highlight it
        var usrmsgs = document.getElementsByClassName('usermessage');
        if(usrmsgs.length > 0) {
            // get the inner text 
            for( let usrmsg of usrmsgs) {
                await console.log("User message is: ", usrmsg);
                if(usrmsg.innerText.includes(searchText)) {
                    var individualWordsArray = usrmsg.innerText.match(/\b(\w|')+\b/gim); //regex to split the entire text into array of individual words
                    console.log("Individual Words array are: ", individualWordsArray);

                    usrmsg.innerHTML = usrmsg.innerHTML.replace(
                        searchText,
                        '<span class="highlight-search-text">' + searchText + '</span>'
                    );

                    individualWordsArray.map((word) => {
                        if(word.includes(searchText)) {
                            // my dummy logic t
                            word = '<span class="highlight-search-text">' + word + '</span>'
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("Individual words array are: ", individualWordsArray);
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: Search only highlights first occurrence within a single chat message]

Requesting experts in JS and HTML for help. Thanks!

Comment: Try `replaceAll` instead of `replace`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dusted off an [old jsFiddle](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/0o5y9fgz), maybe it gives you ideas:

```js
runExamples();

/** highLighter CODE**/
function highLight(term, hlClass = "highlight", root = document.body) {

  if (!term) {
    throw TypeError('Highlighter needs a term to highlight anything');
  }
  
  term = term instanceof Array ? term.join("|") : term;
  hlClass =  hlClass || "highlight";
  const highlighter = a => `<span class="${hlClass}">${a}</span>`;
  const toHtml = node => node.innerHTML =
    node.innerHTML.replace(/&lt;/g, "<").replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
  const children = root.childNodes;

  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i += 1) {
    // recurse children if applicable
    if (children[i].childNodes.length) {
      highLight.call(null, term, hlClass, children[i]);
    }

    let node = children[i];
    let re = RegExp(`(${term})`, "gi");

    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && re.test(node.data)) {
      node.data = node.data.replace(re, highlighter);
      toHtml(node.parentElement);
    }
  }
}

function runExamples() {
  // highlight the words 'ante', set', 'vul' and 'lacus'
  // within the first p of everything within div#example
  highLight("ante,sit,vul,lacus".split(","),  "highlight2", document.querySelector("#example p:first-child"));

  // highlight the word 'magna' everywhere in the document, using class highlight2
  highLight("magna", "highlight2");

  // highlight the words 'dictum' or 'vestibulum' everywhere in the document 
  // but only in p elements, using class highlight3
  highLight("dictum|vestibulum", "highlight3");

  // highlight the word 'example' within h3 element
  highLight("example", null, document.querySelector("h3"));

  document.addEventListener("click", manual);
}

function manual(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.id.endsWith("Highlight")) {
    console.clear();
    const removeHighligts = () => document.querySelectorAll("[class^='highlight']")
      .forEach(el => el.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(el.textContent)));

    if (origin.id.startsWith("manual")) {
      const inputValue = document.querySelector("input").value.trim();

      if (inputValue) {
        removeHighligts();
        highLight(inputValue, document.querySelector("#highlighter").value);
      }
    }

    if (origin.id.startsWith("remove")) {
      removeHighligts();
    }
    
    if (origin.id.startsWith("example")) {
      removeHighligts();
      runExamples();
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px/15px normal verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.highlight {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #ffffc0;
}

.highlight2 {
    background: orange;
    font-style: italic;
}

.highlight3 {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}


.inline {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>a Lorem Ipsum example</h3>
<div id="example">
  <div id="lipsum">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas molestie, dolor at posuere egestas,
      justo erat molestie ligula, non laoreet justo leo in risus. Aenean ac fermentum mauris. Nam fringilla
      accumsan nunc, at egestas ante vulputate at. Aenean et arcu ut elit gravida ornare. Nam nec eros massa,
      vel imperdiet lorem. Donec dictum, elit vitae commodo porttitor, urna risus fermentum mauris, sit amet
      convallis elit tellus et ligula. <span data-x="demonstrate recursive">Cras nibh lacus</span>, blandit
      eu imperdiet nec, aliquet vitae nibh. Aenean eleifend vestibulum tempor. Vivamus vitae erat quis elit
      fringilla aliquam.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vestibulum molestie erat quis tortor tincidunt fermentum. Mauris imperdiet cursus auctor. Quisque non
      lacinia libero. Sed sed nisi massa, ut vestibulum metus. Nunc ac varius turpis. Pellentesque habitant morbi
      tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque at tellus ligula.
      Aliquam iaculis lacus eget massa tristique accumsan. Integer eu enim sapien, id pretium erat. Ut convallis
      dictum lacus, eget mattis magna molestie ut. Proin pretium mattis nisl, a auctor velit aliquam eget.
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter highlight term" value="sit|lorem|example">
      <select id="highlighter">
        <option value="highlight" selected>default</option>
        <option value="highlight2">orange</option>
        <option value="highlight3">red</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="manualHighlight">highlight manually</button>
      <button id="removeHighlight">remove all highlights</button>
      <button id="exampleHighlight">run examples</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is tweaking your replace function to include a global replace.

```js
_scrollChatMessageAndHighlightResult = (searchText) => {
  // perform DOM operations to find the text and highlight it
  var usrmsgs = document.getElementsByClassName('usermessage');
  if (usrmsgs.length > 0) {
    // get the inner text 
    for (let usrmsg of usrmsgs) {
      if (usrmsg.innerText.includes(searchText)) {
        var individualWordsArray = usrmsg.innerText.match(/\b(\w|')+\b/gim); //regex to split the entire text into array of individual words
        console.log("Individual Words array are: ", individualWordsArray);

        usrmsg.innerHTML = usrmsg.innerHTML.replace(
          RegExp(searchText, "g"), // create a regexp from the searchText and add the "g" flag to make it global
          '<span class="highlight-search-text">' + searchText + '</span>'
        );

        individualWordsArray.map((word) => {
          if (word.includes(searchText)) {
            // my dummy logic t
            word = '<span class="highlight-search-text">' + word + '</span>'
          }
        });
        console.log("Individual words array are: ", individualWordsArray);
      }
    }
  }
}
_scrollChatMessageAndHighlightResult("ha")
```

```css
.highlight-search-text {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="usermessage">
  ha ha haha
</div>
```